# html5 audio do not support in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-audio

This is my code this audio format does not work in mobile please help me how to work audio in mobile browser

```
<html>
    <body>
        <audio  autoplay loop id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
            <source src="wedding.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
            <source src="wedding.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <audio  autoplay loop id="myVideo" width="320" height="176">
  <source src="wedding.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="wedding.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="blast" src="blast.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="smash" src="smash.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="pow" src="pow.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="bang" src="bang.mp3"></audio>
<!-- Background Track -->
<audio id="smooth-jazz" src="smooth-jazz.mp3" autoplay></audio>
```

Then say you have a gun trigger with a class of blasterTrigger:

Shoot!
You could then use the Javascript API to control the playing of the blast sound when the trigger is clicked like so:

```
var blasterTrigger = document.querySelector(".blasterTrigger");
blasterTrigger.addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.getElementById("blast").play();
});
```

[Source of above code](http://matt-harrison.com/perfect-web-audio-on-ios-devices-with-the-web-audio-api/)

**OR**

You can use some HTML5 Audio / Video Library:-

- [jplayer](http://jplayer.org/)
- [mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/) etc.